# What does `client` header value represents in devise_token_auth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-token-auth

I am trying to implement token based authorization in rails, with devise_token_auth (https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth#conceptual).

When I post `uid` and `password` against `sign_in` method, it returns `access-token`, `client` (and `uid` itself) in header.  I understand that token based authorization works like this:

1. User posts `uid`(id) and `password` to api server.
2. Api server validates the `uid` and `password`
3. Issues Token and returns it, if the `uid` and `password` matched.
4. Client receives the Token.
5. Client whenever client wants to access the authentication required apis, Client uses the `uid` and the Token in order to prove that this client is in fact already authenticated.

I can understand that `access-token` corresponds to the Token described in above explanation.  That leads to me a question of what the `client` header value is, because it seems that, according to the official Wiki (https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth#usage-tldr),  devise_auth_token library not only use requires `access-token` but also `client` value.

#### Question:

- In devise_token_auth, what is the purpose of `client` header value?  Why is it also needed for identifying the user?  Couldn't that be included in (or, concatenated to) the `access-token` value?

Answer (score 1):

The `client` header is generated for every different device accessing the API. Its purpose is to maintain more than one session active for a specific user (web client, mobile client, etc.).

You can test this by signing in with the same user on 2 separate web clients and checking `user.tokens`, there should be 1 set of tokens for every client.